# Dynamic languages on elasticsearch analyzer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, mongoid

I am new to elasticsearch and try to make the analyzing language of my document fields dynamic. So in german written documents should be indexed as german, and of course english written documents should be written in english. My approach fails with "country method not found".

```
class MyDocument

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  field :content, type: String # lorem ipsum
  field :country, type: String # AT

  settings do
    mapping do
      indexes :content, analyzer: (['AT', 'DE', 'CH'].include? country ? 'german' : 'english')
    end
  end
end
```

How can I achieve that? Or is that not possible.

Comment: Is this something you are looking for - https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Knowledge%20Center%20full%20documentation-v3/GUID-B5E45129-2832-4233-8CDC-E50B76823D47

Comment: not really. I dont know how to get the "country" field into my mapping index. It is not reachable from within the mapping. Of course I can wrap the "settings/mapping" block into a `['AT', 'DE', 'CH'].include? country`, but I thought it's easier to read

Comment: Ohh, perhaps you can try the alternate first. We can check if that gives what we want. If it works, it would be easier to analyze the problem.

Comment: You'll have to use index template, see here https://github.com/GSA/i14y/blob/master/README.md